# How rotate Principal Component Analysis (PCA) obtained from “pcaPP” package of R

Tags: r, rstudio, pca

I have this code in R-Studio:

```
# x is my data
library(pcaPP)

pc  <-  PCAproj(x)
```

How we can rotate result using `varimax`?

Documentation link : [pcaPP](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FpcaPP%2FpcaPP.pdf&ei=L0pnVb_NMIrq8gXxnoKgAw&usg=AFQjCNGMkyhEbfo_pljpJA8Gp0KnwX5tcA&bvm=bv.93990622,d.dGc)